# HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source in mockito

Tags: java

I am performing unit tests using mockito to return a dataSource using HikariDataSource,
but inform that you cannot get the connection to the network.
I understand that being a mock it is not necessary to hit the correct URL

```
07:24:50.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - Driver class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver found in Thread context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7106e68e
07:24:50.982 [main] WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - HikariPool-1 - maxLifetime is less than 30000ms, setting to default 1800000ms.
07:24:50.982 [main] WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - HikariPool-1 - idleTimeout has been set but has no effect because the pool is operating as a fixed size pool.
07:24:50.982 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - HikariPool-1 - configuration:
07:24:50.987 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - allowPoolSuspension.............false
07:24:50.988 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - autoCommit......................true
07:24:50.988 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - catalog.........................none
07:24:50.988 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionInitSql...............none
07:24:50.988 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTestQuery.............none
07:24:50.988 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTimeout...............20000
07:24:50.988 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSource......................none
07:24:50.988 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceClassName.............none
07:24:50.988 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceJNDI..................none
07:24:50.989 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
07:24:50.989 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - driverClassName................."oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
07:24:50.989 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - exceptionOverrideClassName......none
07:24:50.989 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckProperties...........{}
07:24:50.989 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckRegistry.............none
07:24:50.989 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - idleTimeout.....................10000
07:24:50.989 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - initializationFailTimeout.......1
07:24:50.990 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - isolateInternalQueries..........false
07:24:50.990 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.55.147:1522:swd126
07:24:50.990 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - leakDetectionThreshold..........0
07:24:50.990 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maxLifetime.....................1800000
07:24:50.990 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maximumPoolSize.................10
07:24:50.990 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricRegistry..................none
07:24:50.990 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricsTrackerFactory...........none
07:24:50.990 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - minimumIdle.....................10
07:24:50.990 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - password........................<masked>
07:24:50.990 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
07:24:50.990 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - readOnly........................false
07:24:50.991 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - registerMbeans..................false
07:24:50.991 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - scheduledExecutor...............none
07:24:50.991 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - schema..........................none
07:24:50.991 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - threadFactory...................internal
07:24:50.991 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - transactionIsolation............default
07:24:50.991 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - username........................"teste"
07:24:50.991 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - validationTimeout...............5000
07:24:50.992 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
07:24:50.998 [main] WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
07:24:50.999 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource - Driver class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver found in Thread context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7106e68e
07:24:54.084 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to create/setup connection: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
07:24:54.086 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:445)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:464)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:594)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:229)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

```
 @Component
        public class ConfigDataSource {
        
            @Autowired
            private Properties properties;
            public DataSource getDataSource(String url, String username, String password) {
                DataSource dataSource = null;
                try {
                    HikariConfig ds = new HikariConfig();
                    ds.setJdbcUrl(url);
                    ds.setUsername(username);
                    ds.setPassword(password);
                    ds.setDriverClassName(properties.getDriveClassName());
                    ds.setConnectionTimeout(properties.getConnectionTimeout());
                    ds.setMinimumIdle(properties.getMinimumIdle());
                    ds.setMaximumPoolSize(properties.getMaximumPoolSize());
                    ds.setIdleTimeout(properties.getIdleTimeout());
                    ds.setMaxLifetime(properties.getMaxLifetime());
                    dataSource = new HikariDataSource(ds);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Error connecting to the database: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                return dataSource;
            }
        }
        
        Mockito:
        
        @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
        public class ConfigDataSourceTest {
            @Mock
           private Properties properties;
        
            @InjectMocks
            private ConfigDataSource configDataSource;
        
            @Test
            public void configDataSourceTest() {
                String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:teste:swd001";
                String userName = "teste";
                String password = "teste";
                String divreClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
                Integer connectionTimeout = 20000;
                Integer minimumIdle = 100;
                Integer maximumPoolSize = 10;
                Integer idleTimeout = 10000;
                Integer maxLifetime = 1000;
        
                when(properties.getDriveClassName()).thenReturn(divreClassName);
                when(properties.getConnectionTimeout()).thenReturn(connectionTimeout);
                when(properties.getMinimumIdle()).thenReturn(minimumIdle);
                when(properties.getMaximumPoolSize()).thenReturn(maximumPoolSize);
                when(properties.getIdleTimeout()).thenReturn(idleTimeout);
                when(properties.getMaxLifetime()).thenReturn(maxLifetime);
                
                
                DataSource result = configDataSource.getDataSource(jdbcUrl, userName, password);
        
                assertNotNull(result);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask